# higher order ODE convert problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, higher-order-logic

I have

$$y'''- 3\,y'- x\,y = 0.$$

How to convert this to three first order differential equations?

I got stuck for using Let $z=y''$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y_1=y$, $y_2=y'$ and $y_3=y''$. Then
$$\begin{align}
y_1'&=y_2\\
y_2'&=y_3\\
y_3'&=y'''=\text{ fill the blank}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: $$y'''=3y'+xy$$ what about next? I have to write it like $$y'=$$

Comment: Well, the definitions tell you how to write $y$ and $y'$ in terms of $y_1$ and $y_2$.